# How do I fix IndexError in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I used this code in my program to find the coordinates of the center of any object:

```
def getx(item):
    pos = c.coords(item)
    return (pos[0] + pos[2]) / 2
def gety(item):
    pos = c.coords(item)
    return (pos[1] + pos[3]) / 2
```

Then when I used the function to find the coordinates of an object, this is what I get:

```
File "example.py", line 64, in getx
    return (pos[0] + pos[2]) / 2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried many things to fix this, but the only solution so far seems to remove that function, which I can't do, because I need it. Does anyone know what the problem is here and how to fix it?

Comment: What is `item`?

Comment: Use `c.bbox(item)` instead of `c.coords(item)`

Comment: `item` is a variable, so if I have a circle named BALL, I can put getx(BALL) and it will give me the x-coordinate of the center.

Comment: @CoOlLaMbOrGhInI If my solution works I will write a proper answer. I think I know the correct answer but not 100% sure.

Comment: I tried using `c.bbox(item)` but now it gives this error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CoOlLaMbOrGhInI Add `print(item, c.coords(item), c.bbox(item))` at the start of the function and check what it returns. I just checked and `.bbox` should work for `tkinter.Canvas` circles (created using `.create_oval`)

Comment: I finally understood the problem! I was accidentally using `getx()` on objects that did not exist yet. Thanks a lot @TheLizzard!